# How to open Modal When Search Box value not matched from database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am creating a search box. When I type on search box for example 'Tec' not open modal its auto selected, when I type Only 'R' then open modal related T value.

```
$('#customer_1').keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        supplier_id =  $("#customerid_1").val();
        if ($('#customerid_1').val() == '') {
            var search_customer = $("#customer_1").val();
            var action = 'search_supplier';
            var dataString = 'search_customer=' + search_customer + '&action=' + action;

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "search_customer.php",
                data: dataString,
                dataType: 'html'
            }).done(function (data) {
                // Open modal popup
                $("#supplier_modal").modal("show");
                $('#dynamic-content').html('');
                $('#dynamic-content').html(data); 
            })
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to say above in your question?

Comment: What is the structure of the returned `data` object?

Comment: i have one field search box when i type search any supplier name and enter than call Ajax and bootstrap modal open if type value not matched.
and if value matched than i want that not open modal just select value on that field

Comment: @FarooqTanveer Can you explain about data result

Answer (score 0):

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AR77S.jpg)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IHdZ.jpg)

PHP Code

```
  $search_supplier = $_POST['search_supplier'];
try {
    $i_query = "SELECT count(*) as count
                                      FROM supplier 
                                     WHERE  company = '$search_supplier'";
    $i_result = $dbcon->prepare($i_query);
    $i_result->execute();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error : " . $e->getMessage();
}


$result = $i_result->fetchAll();

if ($result[0]["count"] > 0) {


    try {
        $item_query = "SELECT v.acct_id, v.company, v.phone, v.email_id, v.address
                       FROM supplier v
                       WHERE  company = '$search_supplier'";
        $item_result = $dbcon->prepare($item_query);
        $item_result->execute();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error : " . $e->getMessage();
    }

} else {
    try {
        $item_query = "SELECT v.acct_id, v.company, v.phone, v.email_id, v.address
                       FROM supplier v
                       WHERE  company LIKE '$search_supplier%'";
        $item_result = $dbcon->prepare($item_query);
        $item_result->execute();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error : " . $e->getMessage();
    }


}


// Create empty array to hold query results
$someArray = [];
// Loop through query and push results into $someArray;
while ($item_row = $item_result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    array_push($someArray, [

        'supplier_name' => $item_row['supplier_name'],
        'phone' => $item_row['phone'],
        'email_id' => $item_row['email_id'],
        'address' => $item_row['address'],


    ]);
}

// Convert the Array to a JSON String and echo it
$someJSON = json_encode($someArray);
echo $someJSON;
```

Jquery Code
$('#supplier').keypress(function (e) {

```
   if (e.which == 13) {


          supplier_id =  $("#supplier_id ").val();
```

var dataString = 'search_customer=' + search_customer;

```
       $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   data: dataString,
                   url: "get_search_supplier",
                   dataType: "json",
                   success: function (JSONObject) {
                       var peopleHTML = "";

                       // Loop through Object and create peopleHTML
                       var i = 1;

                       for (var key in JSONObject) {
                           if (JSONObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

                               peopleHTML += '<tr style="text-align: center;">';
                               peopleHTML += '<td class="btnSelect" style="display: none;">' + JSONObject[key]["acct_id"] + '</td>';
                               peopleHTML += '<td class="btnSelect" style="cursor: pointer;">' + JSONObject[key]["company"] + '</td>';
                               peopleHTML += '<td class="btnSelect" style="cursor: pointer;">' + JSONObject[key]["phone"] + '</td>';
                               peopleHTML += '<td class="btnSelect" style="cursor: pointer;">' + JSONObject[key]["email_id"] + '</td>';
                               peopleHTML += '<td class="btnSelect" style="cursor: pointer;" >' + JSONObject[key]["address"] + '</td>';
                               peopleHTML += '</tr>';








                                   $("#supplier_modal").modal("show");
                                   $("#supplier_modal tbody").html(peopleHTML);



                           }

                       }


                   }
               });




       }
```

});

i have one field search box when i type search any supplier name and enter than call Ajax and bootstrap modal open if type value not matched. and if value matched than i want that not open modal just select value on that field